# World Space Ambient Occlusion

Tags: rendering, eevee-render-engine, render-passes, ambient-occlusion

Gotta question about Eevee rendering.
Normally, Eevee uses screen space ambient occlusion and screen space stuff obviously generates lots of artifacts, like the one on the picture, where the occlusion on the building ceases near the edge of the estacade, which is closer to the camera. Is there any way to use more realistic AO rendering method for Eevee? Something that might be called "world space ambient occlusion"? Something closer to Cycles, at the obvious performance cost?

[image]

Comment: What if I add AO node to the materials? Is it going to avoid the glitch?

Answer (score 2):

Well I assume you are already familiar with how cycles and Eevee rendering works. Like you said Eevee uses fake/cheat method. What you are asking for is achieve Cycles like AO which is physically accurate (depends on the values on a given scene). Currently there's no proven working method that achieves that, I can suggest you to bake the AO in Eevee like we bake in light from Cycles.

Comment: Sure, thank you, I'll try that. But baking AO means I can no longer edit the mesh, right? Because AO will basically become an image texture and mapping will be messed up after any geometry change, right?

Comment: Yes that's correct. It's much effective in static objects in the scene. If that's not ideal in your situation then you can play with nodes in Shader editor and compositor. I've not tried that myself but I'm sure there are ways to hacks achieve that effect

Comment: Sure, I'll try that. Thank you!